# batch file to Rename file by text AND Current Folder name

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have a batch file that sits in c:\test and images that sit in c:\test\1\ and c:\test\2

I have a batch command that will recursively precede the name of each jpeg file found with the text "Album_" e.g "image001.jpg" becomes "Album_image001.jpg"
This works prefectly, but i want it to add the current folder name
E.g I want the image to be named Album_**1**image001.jpg

here is the current batch command

```
forfiles /S /M *.jpg /C "cmd /c rename @file Album_@file"
```

Comment: Use `for /R` command where you can add folder path and use *.jpg for all jpeg file.

Answer (score 1):

If there are only the two folders you mention, this should work:

```
forfiles /P 1 /M *.jpg /C "cmd /c rename @file Album_1@file"
forfiles /P 2 /M *.jpg /C "cmd /c rename @file Album_2@file"
```